# In JNI, can you pass a C integer parameter to a Java primitive int?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a Java method that wish to be called from some Native method:

```
    public void onDownloadProgress(int current, int total) {

    }
```

and I am trying to call the above Java method from a native method:

```
    int current = ...
    int total = ...
    jni_callVoidMethod(
        env,
        jDownloadCallback,
        "onDownloadProgress",
        "(II)V",
        current,
        total
    );
```

**jni_callVoidMethod** is a helper method and its implementation is:

```
    void jni_callVoidMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject receiver, const char *methodName, const char *contract, ...) {
        jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(receiver);
            if (NULL != clazz) {
            jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(
            clazz,
            methodName,
            contract
        );
        if (NULL != method) {
            BUILD_VARARGS()
                env->CallVoidMethodV(
                receiver,
                method,
                va_args
            );
        if (env->ExceptionCheck()) { // prints out the exception if one is present
            env->ExceptionDescribe();
            env->ExceptionClear();
        }
        va_end(va_args);
        }
        env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);
    }
}
```

However, in the Java method I am getting some very weird int values. For example, 3840120912. I am wondering can you directly send a C int to a Java primitive int instead of declaring the parameters in the Java method to become Integer type? Declaring those two parameters to be Integer works for me and I am getting the correct value.

Edit:
Implementation of the **BUILD_VARARGS** macro:

```
#define BUILD_VARARGS() \
va_list va_args; \
va_start(va_args, contract); \
const char *cur = contract; \
while ('\0' != *cur && '(' != *cur) { /* skip to opening paren */ \
    cur++; \
} \
while ('\0' != *cur && ')' != *cur) { /* stop at closing paren */ \
    switch (*cur) { \
        case 'Z': \
            va_arg(va_args, int); /* bool (unsigned 8-bit int) */ \
            break; \
        case 'B': \
            va_arg(va_args, int); /* byte (signed 8-bit int) */ \
            break; \
        case 'C': \
            va_arg(va_args, int); /* char (unsigned 16-bit int) */ \
            break; \
        case 'S': \
            va_arg(va_args, int); /* short (signed 16-bit int) */ \
            break; \
        case 'I': \
            va_arg(va_args, long long); /* int (signed 32-bit int) (must be passed in as a long long) */ \
            break; \
        case 'J': \
            va_arg(va_args, long); /* long (signed 64-bit int) */ \
            break; \
        case 'F': \
            va_arg(va_args, double); /* float (32 bits) */ \
            break; \
        case 'D': \
            va_arg(va_args, double); /* double (64 bits) */ \
            break; \
        case 'L': \
            /* fully-qualified-class */ \
            while (';' != *++cur && '\0' != *cur); /* advance to end of class declaration */ \
            /* FIXME breaks varargs, seems to not be needed va_arg(va_args, jobject); */ \
            break; \
        case '[': \
            /* TODO type type[] */ \
        case '(': \
            /* TODO ( arg-types ) ret-type  method type */ \
        default: \
            break; \
    } \
    cur++; \
}
```

Comment: Try `jni_callVoidMethod(env, ..., "(II)V", (jint) current, (jint) total);`. My guess is you're using 64-bit `int` but Java accepts them as 32-bit values, corrupting stack.

Comment: If the problem is as @vbezhenar suggests, in your C code you can `#include <stdint.h>` and use `int32_t` instead of `int` for your variables in C.

Comment: @vbezhenar, I tried your suggestion and it did not work out. I hardcoded int current = 1 and int total = 413, and in the Java I am getting 366961048 from current and 375649488 from total.

Comment: What does `BUILD_VARARGS` look like?

Comment: What @Botje said. And where does jni_CallVoidMethod come from anyway? Can you first try without using it, i.e. call `GetObjectClass`, `GetMethodID` and `CallVoidMethod` (without the "V") directly. This way you don't run the risk of messing up the varargs.

Comment: also, does `vfprintf("current:%d total:%d\n", va_args)` work properly?

Comment: @Botje, I have added the BUILD_VARARGS implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That explains everything! Your calls to `va_arg` consume the arguments and when `CallVoidMethodV` gets to it, it is reading from somewhere else in the stack. From the `va_arg` manual:

> The va_arg() macro expands to an expression that has the type and value
>        of the next argument in the call.  The parameter ap is the va_list ap
>        initialized by va_start().
>        **Each call to va_arg() modifies ap so that the
>        next call returns the next argument.**

Instead, you should create the `va_list` and immediately hand it off to `CallVoidMethodV`:

```
va_list va_args;
va_start(va_args, contract);
env->CallVoidMethodV(receiver, method, va_args);
va_end(va_args);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!